# OCaml 3.12.0 64 bit for Windows 7 64

Tags: ocaml

On http://caml.inria.fr/download.en.html I can only find the version 3.11.0 for Windows 32. Is there a precompiled OCaml 3.12.0 for Windows 64?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537825/why-there-is-no-binary-distribution-for-ocaml-on-win64

Answer (score 5):

To provide a tidbit of information that could also have been provided [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537825/why-there-is-no-binary-distribution-for-ocaml-on-win64) (but wasn't), there are roughly three categories of supported targets for the OCaml compilers.

In the first category, common architectures, binaries are provided by INRIA: Windows 32-bit, Linux, Mac OS X.

Targets platforms in the second category are those for which they have one installation. INRIA OCaml developers can reproduce bugs specific to that platform if you report them, but none is using the platform as its main development platform, and it would be too much work for them to release binaries for all platforms in this category.

Target platforms in the third category are those they do not have immediate access to.

64-bit Windows is a second-tier platform.